# Create a private key from two public keys that share primes

Tags: prime-numbers, cryptography, prime-factorization

Given two public keys, `n1` and `n2` (and `e` the exponent)--how would one generate a private key for `n1`? In this scenario, `n1` and `n2` share primes.

I know I need to use $$d = e^{-1} \space mod \space (p-1)(q-1)$$--but we don't know `p` or `q`. How would you go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that $n_1$ and $n_2$ are RSA moduli: the common prime $p$ is $\gcd(n_1, n_2)$, easily computable by Euclid's algorithm. We then know $q = \frac{n_1}{p}$ and now you're good to go.

Comment: Thank you! I was just about to post this as an answer myself.